# Subscribe to the change in the value of a variable in an Angular service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

How can I subscribe to the change in the value of a variable in an Angular service?

I have done quite a bit of searching, but cannot find the solution (if it is even possible!).

I have a `component` that is part of my layout (header), which shows the number of items in the cart. This value is bound to the variable `simsInCartLength`

I then have a `service` that handles the adding and removing of items from the cart. In the `service` I have a variable called `noSims` that stores the length of the array of items in the cart.

How can I subscribe to the changes to the service variable, noSims?

**Code in my Component:**

```
simsInCartLength = this.cartService.noSims;
```

**Code in my Service (the variable gets updated when an item is added or removed from the cart:**

```
this.noSims = this.simsInCart.length;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you share your code in stackbiltz

Comment: use Subject or EventEmitter which will be used when value is changed

Comment: You should make your noSims in the service an observable so it can push events when it changes.

Comment: @AndreiTătar I have tried this, but get the following error when the variable is initialized: `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>`'. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `BehaviorSubject` in your service as below:

```
private cartItemCount = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
cartItem = [];

getCartItemCount(){
   return this.cartItemCount.asObservable();
}

addToCart(obj: any){
   this.cartItem.push(obj);
   // some operation to add item in cart and then call next() of observable to emit the new value event
   this.cartItemCount.next(this.cartItem.length)
}

// similar code for removeFromCart()
```

and **in your component** subscribe to that event as:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.cartService.getCartItemCount().subscribe(len => {
     console.log(len) // your new cart length here
     this.simsInCartLength  = len;
  })
}
```